# Подсчет активных товаров в битриксе (не считая деактивированных)

Tags: битрикс

Как правильно делать подсчет активных товаров в битриксе (не считая деактивированных)?

В моем случае 1 товар деактивирован, а второй активен, но показывает что 2 товара (должен быть 1). Как это исправить?

Код выглядит таким образом: `<? echo $arSection['ELEMENT_CNT']; ?>` товара.

Битрикс версии 16.0.9

Answer (score 1):

Используйте стандартный компонент bitrix:catalog

```
$cAllItems = $arResult['NAV_RESULT'];
$cAllItems = $cAllItems -> NavRecordCount;
echo $cAllItems;
```